# Image recognize result issue with google API

Tags: camera, google-api

Currently we are working on Image recognize iOS application. We have used Google API for same, however we are facing very bizarre issue. When we are captured the photo from the mobile app it shows us different result and when we are uploading the image on Google website it's recognize perfect and showing us accurate result.

Here are screenshots.

**Mobile app result:** 
[image]

**Google website result:** 
[image]